# scrape php data for Facebook share

Tags: php, facebook, web-scraping

i want to add a "Share" button and i need the share dialog to reflect information pulled from PHP data base

The developers page refers to the following tags to be included.

```
<meta property="og:url"                content="" />
<meta property="og:type"               content="" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="" />
<meta property="og:image"              content="" />
```

however, i need the content to be pulled  from specific PHP Database information.

```
 <meta property="og:url"                content="" />
 <meta property="og:type"               content="" />
 <meta property="og:title"              content="<?php .$info['full_name'] .;?
 > <?php .$info['last_name'] .;?>" />
 <meta property="og:description"        content="" />
 <meta property="og:image"              content="<?php echo $info['avatar']; ?
 >" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you (though you may need to tweak some parts, depending how your server is set up):

```
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo htmlentities('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URl']) ?>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo htmlentities($info['full_name']) ?> <?php echo htmlentities($info['last_name']) ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $info['avatar']; ?>" />
```

Comment: {
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104
   }
}

Comment: I don't know where you're getting that error but it's not related to this question. You should create a new Stack Overflow question.